# Typescript isn't validating data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, type-conversion

In my React app I have an object that contains components as well as their inputs. It looks like this:

```
<ComManager matrix={[
    [
        {
            Component: SpecificCom, id: "1"
        },
        {
            Component: SpecificCom2
        }
    ], [
        {
            Component: SpecificCom2, nonexistentprop: "1"
        },
        {
            Component: SpecificCom2, value: [1,2,3]
        }
    ]
]}/>
```

Then ComManager takes over to put the list together and actually calls the components and populates them with data:

```
interface ComProps {
    Component: React.FC<any>,
    [key:string]: any
}

interface ComManagerProps {
    matrix: ComProps[][]
}

const ComManager = ({matrix}: ComManagerProps) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {
                matrix.map((v, i) => {
                    return v.map((c, j) => <div key={i}>
                            <c.Component
                                key={`${i}-${j}`} 
                                className="text-2xl"
                                {...c}/>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Lastly, there are the actual components "SpecificCom", "SpecificCom2"... Each may have a set of different inputs (props) that should be validated:

```
export interface SComType {
    className?: string,
    id: string,
}

const SpecificCom = ({className, id}: SComType) => {
    return (
        <div className={className}>
            SCOM component text {id}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Another component has same structure but there's an input called "value" which is string:

```
export interface SComType2 {
    className?: string,
    value: string,
}

const SpecificCom2 = ({className, value}: SComType2) => {
    return (
        <div className={className}>
            SCOM component text {value}
        </div>
    )
}
```

None of these fields are properly validated, all fields are easily transformed into strings and when defined are rendered onto the page. Here's the output:

[image]

#### Question:

I want Typescript to actually verify types defined in SpecificCom components so that the data couldn't be wrongly defines. Would it be possible to solely use Typescript in this case or am I required to create additional validation procedure to validate the original object?

This object has to be invalid:

```
Component: SpecificCom, id: "1"               // correct prop & type
Component: SpecificCom2                       // no prop
Component: SpecificCom2, nonexistentprop: "1" // incorrect prop
Component: SpecificCom2, value: [1,2,3]       // incorrect type
```

*Just in case the project with code is in this branch: https://github.com/Alina-Yermolenko/instalina/tree/feature/version1*

Comment: If you downvote the question please let me know the reason. I tried to put it up as thin as possible to make it still understandable and easily readable. I'll update the question if I know how.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but Stack Overflow is a question and answer platform. Do you have a question?

Comment: @jabaa thank you, I have updated the question with a bit more emphasis on the actual question.

Comment: I think I actually understand what I did wrong. `ComManager` transforms all props to `any` which is compatible with anything so the receiving component won't ever argue about their types, although they may be incorrect. I don't want to add the typing of each component to the ComManager because it just adds another step to it, there may be a lot of components and having type of each imported into Manager object may just be very tedious so that's what I'm trying to avoid at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be one example to make it work:

```
        <div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <SpecificCom id="1" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <SpecificCom2 value="2" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <SpecificCom2 value="3" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <div></div>
                <SpecificCom2 value="4" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

This way all data is validated against components directly although I lose some of the benefits of the original approach. I'd still like to move the each parent div to a separate component to have separate logic and state for each of them, but I see no way to provide validation which returns back to the original question.